# Why aren't error thrown when I run this function as domain administrator?

Tags: powershell, file-permissions

This script is intended to recurse through a series of directories and when an error of type `DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft` or `PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand` is thrown it's supposed to call another function `Take-Ownership` which takes ownership of the directory and adds full permissions for the localAdmin and domain admin to the folder.  (It's really a script used for easing the deletion of old user profiles):

```
function Test-Folder($FolderToTest, $localAdminName) {
    # Remeber the old error preference...
    $old_ErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

    $error.Clear()

    # Go through the directories...and capture errors in $error 
    Get-ChildItem $FolderToTest -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable errz | Select FullName

    Write-Host $errz.count

    if ($errz.Count -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "blah no errors"
        foreach ($err in $errz) { 
            Write-Host "Error: $err"
            if ($err.FullyQualifiedErrorId -eq "DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand") {
                Write-Host Unable to access $err.TargetObject -Fore Red
                Write-Host Attempting to take ownership of $err.TargetObject -Fore Yellow
                Take-Ownership -Folder $err.TargetObject, -LocalAdminName $localAdminName
                Test-Folder -FolderToTest $err.TargetObject -localAdminName $localAdminName
            }
        }
    }

    $ErrorActionPreference = $old_ErrorActionPreference 
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't throw any errors when I run it as domain administrator.  I've found a list of ErrorActionPreferences [here](https://superwidgets.wordpress.com/2014/12/22/powershell-erroraction/), but the errors just seem to get ignored, and it outputs `blah no errors` What can I do to make sure I receive errors and that my `Take-Ownership` function is actually called?

Comment: If I'm unlikely to get an answer here, please transfer this to the serverfault stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only enters the `if` block if `$errz.Count` is 0. With a count of 0 there are no elements in `$errz`, so there's nothing to do for the `foreach` loop.

Add an `else` branch to the conditional, move the `foreach` loop there, and the code should do what you want.

```
if ($errz.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "blah no errors"
} else {
    foreach ($err in $errz) { 
        Write-Host "Error: $err"
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Well okay that's true...but I get a zero error count when it hits the 'Write-Host Errz.Count', that's more my source of confusion.  If I can't get into the directory with the admin account it should throw an exception right?

Comment: Yes. And it did when I tested it. Are you certain that there are subfolders under `$FolderToTest` that the admin can't access? Do you get error output when you change the error action to `Continue`?